# Strange behavior in tabular environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Can someone explain why "B1" cell is not vertically centered and how to figure this out ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.3\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.2\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.15\textwidth}}

\begin{tabular}{|A|B|C|D|}
\hline C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 \\ 
\hline Type 1 &

 $\begin{matrix}
 eq_1 \\
 eq_2
 \end{matrix}$

& A1  & B1 \\[3cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you asking for `m` columns?

Comment: @egreg : Because `m` is suppose to do the job (vertical-alignment) and it doesn't !

Comment: It is a known problem: the vertical space is added to the last column. Add a row, instead: `&&&\\[3cm]`

Comment: Ok, problem solved ! 
"It is a known problem" Well, not for me apparently !
The trick is to add a hidden column with `@{}m{0pt}@{}`
Thanks egreg !

Comment: Don't worry: it's not easy to search the site, but the experienced users are here just for helping out.